# Reading values from incomplete table in Python

Tags: python, file

I need to read some values from a table in Python. The column I need is the last one, however many rows don't have all the values filled. This is a part of it, and I need to read the numbers in the last column.

```
XMSJ 233156.2+195123 23 31 56.2 +19 51 22.6  22.98  22.06  21.15       Y BLAGN 0.718
XMSJ 233158.7+194440 23 31 58.8 +19 44 39.2  23.47  22.24  21.21       Y BLAGN 1.418
XMSJ 233201.5+200406 23 32 01.5 +20 04 06.4                            Y BLAGN 1.517
XMSJ 233203.2+200626 23 32 03.2 +20 06 27.7  21.07  20.36  20.12 19.30 Y BLAGN 1.901
XMSJ 233207.3+200529 23 32 07.4 +20 05 29.1  22.26  21.61  21.48       Y BLAGN 1.897
XMSJ 233209.8+194517 23 32 09.8 +19 45 17.4  20.26  19.05  18.37 19.30 Y BLAGN 2.027
```

I tried this `data = np.genfromtxt(dataset, unpack=True, usecols=(14,), invalid_raise=False)` but this just skips the rows which are not complete, while I still want these values (the output here would be `NA NA NA 1.901 NA 2.027`, while I need `0.718 1.418 1.517 1.901 1.897 2.027`. Can someone tell me how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `np.genfromtxt` doesn't know what to do with the blank fields. As far as it understands, any contiguous white spaces are squashed as one white space, and it can't guess which value is supposed to be for which field.

This is taken staight from the [`numpy.genfromtxt` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html): "When spaces are used as delimiters, or when no delimiter has been given as input, there should not be any missing data between two fields."

What you can do, if the fields in the rows have constant length, is to split the rows into the desired columns explicitly first:

```
rows = []
with open('table.txt') as table_file:
    for line in table_file:
        row = [
            line[0:4],  # XMSJ
            line[5:20], # 233156.2+195123
            # etc.
        ]

        # TODO: find blank values within the row; and replace them
        # with None, NaN, or some other appropriate dummy value.
        # Left as an exercise for you.

        rows.append(row)

data = np.array(rows) # but of course you probably want to type-cast the columns properly, also left as an exercise.
```

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, it works here, but not all the files have the same structure and this would mean to adjust the code for each file. I would like a more general way of doing it.

Comment: @BillKet Given columns that have constant widths, it is probably possible to write a function that detects the columns. Basically you would need two passes over the whole table. The first pass to detect the column widths. The second pass to do the splitting.

Comment: @BillKet In fact, you could probably use regex to help you detect the columns.

You are basically looking for all the whitespace to non-whitespace boundaries using regex.